# creating a repeatable test for a PhantomReference application

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Consider a library that uses PhantomReferences to avoid finalizers while also ensuring that some JNI resources get freed.

One architecture involves the reference queue and a thread blocking on the reference queue that does the cleanup.

Now comes the question: how to make a test for all of this?

1. Set up system
2. Create an object of interest
3. let it become garbage
4. System.gc()
5. somehow wait for the thread to wake up, smell the coffee, and do the job
6. assert that an internal counter is ticked to prove that all of this happened

`Thread.sleep()` is effective but disturbing for item 5. `Thread.yield()` isn't reliable at all. What other options are there, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make changes to the library in question, then pass an optional `BlockingQueue<Reference?>>` into the cleanup code, so that it can signal completion.  If the queue exists, the cleanup code enqueues the reference to the queue after cleanup is performed.  The test code can call `BlockingQueue.poll(timeout)` -- either receiving the reference as soon as cleanup has completed, or timing out if cleanup hasn't completed within some reasonable upperbound timeout time which you determine.

Comment: So, how is choosing a big enough value for 'timeout' different from choosing a big enough value for 'sleep'?

Comment: Tests written with the timeout approach will complete much faster.  The sleep approach waits for the max. acceptable time to elapse, whereas the timeout approach terminates as soon as the cleanup has been performed, which could be much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are running with less than 2GB heap, allocating a byte array just smaller than the available heap size should trigger an immediate, full gc before the expected OutOfMemoryError is thrown:

`byte[] foo = new byte[(int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()-1)];`

I wouldn't make the byte array *larger* than the heap size, since the VM In that case may throw an OutOfMemoryError immediately, since it knows that it cannot provide that much heap anyway.

Comment: The problem isn't triggering the GC. System.gc seems to do that. The problem is waiting for the thread that waits on the ReferenceQueue to actually get awakened to do its work.

Comment: Sorry, I though you wanted to wait for the gc thread to wake up and do it's job. The behaviour is odd. Soft and weak references are enqueued in the reference queue immediately when the gc runs, but for some reason, the phantom references are enqueued much later. Waiting a second and triggering the gc a second time seem to do the trick, but that is not a good idea either.